# Sending a stream of documents to a Jersey @POST endpoint

Tags: java, rest, jersey, streaming

I want to be able to **send** a stream of a bunch of documents to a web service. This will save on Http request/response overhead and focus on the documents themselves.

In python you can do something like this:

```
r = requests.post('https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json',
    data={'track': 'requests'}, auth=('username', 'password'),
    stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line: # filter out keep-alive new lines
        print json.loads(line)
```

I'm looking for an example of someone streaming a Request to a Jersey rest api. I was hoping to see the client side and the server side to show it working. But i'm struggling hard to find an example out there.

The example Ideally would show:

```
Client:
  Open request
  Iterate over huge document list
    Write document to open request stream
  Close request

Server:
  @POST method
    Open entity stream
    Iterate over entity stream while next document is available
        Process document
    Close entity stream
```

If we get it right you'll be processing entities on the Server while still sending them on the Client! Huge win!

Comment: If your client and server are both Jersey-based, you could try [ChunkedOutput](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#chunked-output) and a corresponding ChunkedInput. I don't know how a client in Javascript would do ChunkedInput, though.

Comment: Is there a reason why we aren't sending the files one-by-one?

Comment: Huge batch process. Interested in speed with few nodes as possible. Streaming will cut out a lot of overhead if i'm thinking this up correctly

Comment: What language is your client?

Comment: Correct me here  , Have  you looked at using AsyncResponse in jax-rs , you could have clients sending requests and on the server side you can have threads created that can resume , process and respond async with futures.

Comment: That won't help cut down on Request/response overhead which i'm trying to avoid. I don't think anyway? @RamachandranGA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to accomplish this is to let Jersey provide the POST handler with an `InputStream` for the HTTP POST body. The method can use the `InputStream` and JSON parser of your choice to parse then handle each object.

In the following example, the a Jackson `ObjectReader` produces a `MappingIterator` which parses and processes each `Person` document in the array as it is delivered to the server

```
/**
 * Parse and process an arbitrarily large JSON array of Person documents
 */
@Path("persons")
public static class PersonResource {

    private static final ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(Person.class);

    @Path("inputstream")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @POST
    public void inputstream(final InputStream is) throws IOException {
        final MappingIterator<Person> persons = reader.readValues(is);
        while (persons.hasNext()) {
            final Person person = persons.next();
            // process
            System.out.println(person);
        }
    }
}
```

Likewise, the Jersey client framework can send a stream of documents when configured with a Jackson `ObjectMapper`. The following example demonstrates this with the Jersey Test framework. The client streams an arbitrarily large iterator of `Person` documents

```
public class JacksonStreamingTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(PersonResource.class, ObjectMapperProvider.class);
    }

    /**
     * Registers the application {@link ObjectMapper} as the JAX-RS provider for application/json
     */
    @Provider
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

        private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> objectType) {
            return mapper;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureClient(final ClientConfig config) {
        config.register(ObjectMapperProvider.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final Set<Person> persons = Collections.singleton(Person.of("Tracy", "Jordan"));
        final Response response = target("persons/inputstream").request().post(Entity.json(persons.iterator()));
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(204);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Does Jetty do any buffering that might affect the performance of this?

Comment: Jersey (not jetty) is the framework that ultimately delivers the `InputStream` to you method decorated with `@POST`, of course, Jersey can run on top of a Jetty server in which case the `InputStream` it delivers may be passed along from Jetty without modification - it's unclear.

The JSON parser probably has its own buffering (Jackson uses a buffer when parsing), but to be certain, you could always first wrap the `InputStream` with a [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)

Comment: OK @jdgilday two things: 

1) without the below snippet the documents would never flush: `clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE, Integer.valueOf(0));`

2) we are losing like ~1% of the documents. I can confirm they are returned from the iterator's `next()` method on the client using the debugger, but for some reason a few docs are not making their way there.

Comment: Lost 1% of the documents because I wasn't committing the last batch! this works!!!