# Issue with streaming formatted input stream to server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, binary, inputstream

I am trying to write a "formatted" input stream to a tomcat servlet (with Guice).

The underlying problem is the following: I want to stream data from a database directly to a server. Therefore I load the data, convert it to JSON and upload it to the server. I don't want to write the JSON to a temporary file first, this is done due to performance issues, so I want to circumvent using the hard drive, by directly streaming to the server.

**EDIT:** Similar to [Sending a stream of documents to a Jersey @POST endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612843/sending-a-stream-of-documents-to-a-jersey-post-endpoint)

But a comment in the answer says that it is loosing data, I seem to have the same problem.

I wrote a "ModelInputStream" that

1. Loads the next model from the database when the previous is streamed
2. Writes one byte for the type (enum ordinal)
3. Writes 4 bytes for the length of the next byte array (int)
4. Writes a string (refId)
5. Writes 4 bytes for the length of the next byte array (int)
6. Writes the actual json
7. Repeat until all models are streamed

I also wrote a "ModelStreamReader" that knows that logic and reads accordingly.

When I test this directly it works fine, but once I create the ModelInputStream on client side and use the incoming input stream on the server with the ModelStreamReader the actual json bytes are less than specified in the 4 bytes defining the length. I guess this is due to deflating or compression.

I tried different content headers for trying to disable compression etc, but nothing worked.

```
java.io.IOException: Unexpected length, expected 8586, received 7905
```

So on Client the JSON byte array is 8586 bytes long and when it arrives at the server it is 7905 bytes long, which breaks the whole concept.

Also it seems that it does not really stream, but first caches the whole content that is returned from the input stream.

How would I need to adjust the calling code to get the result I described?

**ModelInputStream**

```
package *;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

import ***.Daos;
import ***.IDatabase;
import ***.CategorizedEntity;
import ***.CategorizedDescriptor;
import ***.JsonExport;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class ModelInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final IDatabase db;
    private final Queue<CategorizedDescriptor> descriptors;
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
    private int position = 0;

    public ModelInputStream(IDatabase db, List<CategorizedDescriptor> descriptors) {
        this.db = db;
        this.descriptors = new LinkedList<>();
        this.descriptors.addAll(descriptors);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (position == buffer.length) {
            if (descriptors.size() == 0)
                return -1;
            loadNext();
            position = 0;
        }
        return buffer[position++];
    }

    private void loadNext() throws IOException {
        CategorizedDescriptor descriptor = descriptors.poll();
        byte type = (byte) descriptor.getModelType().ordinal();
        byte[] refId = descriptor.getRefId().getBytes();
        byte[] json = getData(descriptor);
        buildBuffer(type, refId, json);
    }

    private byte[] getData(CategorizedDescriptor d) {
        CategorizedEntity entity = Daos.createCategorizedDao(db, d.getModelType()).getForId(d.getId());
        JsonObject object = JsonExport.toJson(entity);
        String json = gson.toJson(object);
        return json.getBytes();
    }

    private void buildBuffer(byte type, byte[] refId, byte[] json) throws IOException {
        buffer = new byte[1 + 4 + refId.length + 4 + json.length];
        int index = put(buffer, 0, type);
        index = put(buffer, index, asByteArray(refId.length));
        index = put(buffer, index, refId);
        index = put(buffer, index, asByteArray(json.length));
        put(buffer, index, json);
    }

    private byte[] asByteArray(int i) {
        return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(i).array();
    }

    private int put(byte[] array, int index, byte... bytes) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            array[index + i] = bytes[i];
        }
        return index + bytes.length;
    }

}
```

**ModelStreamReader**

```
package *;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import *.ModelType;

public class ModelStreamReader {

    private InputStream stream;

    public ModelStreamReader(InputStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public Model next() throws IOException {
        int modelType = stream.read();
        if (modelType == -1)
            return null;
        Model next = new Model();
        next.type = ModelType.values()[modelType];
        next.refId = readNextPart();
        next.data = readNextPart();
        return next;
    }

    private String readNextPart() throws IOException {
        int length = readInt();
        byte[] bytes = readBytes(length);
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    private int readInt() throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = readBytes(4);
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();
    }

    private byte[] readBytes(int length) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        int read = stream.read(buffer);
        if (read != length)
            throw new IOException("Unexpected length, expected " + length + ", received " + read);
        return buffer;
    }

    public class Model {

        public ModelType type;
        public String refId;
        public String data;

    }

}
```

**Calling Code**

```
ModelInputStream stream = new ModelInputStream(db, getAll(db));
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/ws/test/streamed");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.connect();
int read = -1;
while ((read = stream.read()) != -1) {
    con.getOutputStream().write(read);
}
con.getOutputStream().flush();
System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
con.disconnect();
```

**Server part** (Jersey WebResource)

```
package *.webservice;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import *.ModelStreamReader;
import *.ModelStreamReader.Model;

@Path("test")
public class TestResource {

    @POST
    @Path("streamed")
    public Response streamed(InputStream modelStream) throws IOException {
        ModelStreamReader reader = new ModelStreamReader(modelStream);
        writeDatasets(reader);
        return Response.ok(new HashMap<>()).build();
    }

    private void writeDatasets(ModelStreamReader reader) throws IOException {
        String commitId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        File dir = new File("/opt/tests/streamed/" + commitId);
        dir.mkdirs();
        Model dataset = null;
        while ((dataset = reader.next()) != null) {
            File file = new File(dir, dataset.refId);
            writeDataset(file, dataset.data);
        }
    }

    private void writeDataset(File file, String data) {
        try {
            if (data == null)
                file.createNewFile();
            else
                Files.write(file.toPath(), data.getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bytes read have to be shifted into the (0, 255) range (see `ByteArrayInputStream`).

**ModelInputStream**

```
@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
    ...
    return buffer[position++] & 0xff;
}
```

Finally this line has to be added to the calling code (for chunking):

```
...
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024 * 1024);
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem which was of a totally different nature.

First the input stream was not compressed or anything. The bytes read have to be shifted into the (0, 255) range instead of (-128, 127). So the stream reading was interrupted by a -1 byte value.

**ModelInputStream**

```
@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
    ...
    return buffer[position++] + 128;
}
```

Second, the data has to be transfered chunked to be actually "streaming". Therefore the ModelStreamReader.readBytes(int) method must be additionally adjusted to:

**ModelStreamReader**

```
private byte[] readBytes(int length) throws IOException {
    byte[] result = new byte[length];
    int totalRead = 0;
    int position = 0;
    int previous = -1;
    while (totalRead != length) {
        int read = stream.read();
        if (read != -1) {
            result[position++] = (byte) read - 128;
            totalRead++;
        } else if (previous == -1) {
            break;
        }
        previous = read;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally this line has to be added to the calling code:

```
...
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024 * 1024);
...
```

Comment: You don't have to shift the bytes or shift them back. Obviously. Doing that accomplishes exactly nothing. You solved some other problem via this redundant process. You seem to be looking for `DataInputStream.readFully()` and friends.

Comment: The values of the bytes are ranged between -128 and 127, so if I don't shift the values it will return negative values, in case of a value of -1 it will terminate the reading of the stream premature. That is what caused the problem, it is working with the code I posted in the answer (incl. the shift)

Comment: Could you please explain why you are downvoting the question and the answer? Why is the question not showing any research effort, and why is the answer not useful. And please elaborate why it is so obvious, apparently it is not obvious to me.

Comment: I checked the ByteArrayInputStream implementation and the way I shifted the bytes was wrong (it worked for my case, but is wrong in general), so I updated the answer accordingly.